# Regex not detecting swear words inside string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a script here:

http://jsfiddle.net/d2rcx/

It has an array of badWords to compare input strings with.

This script works fine if the input string matches exactly as the swear word string but it does not pick up any variations where there is more characters in the string e.g. whitespace before the swear word.

Using this site as reference : http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm

It said the following regex would detect a string within a string.

```
var regex = new RegExp("/" + badWords[i] + "/g");
        if (fieldValue.match(regex) == true)
            return true;
```

However that does not seem to be the case.

What do I need to change to the regex to make it work.

Thanks

Also any good links to explain Regex than what google turns up would be appreciated.

Comment: This kind of searching will lead to false positives (much to the annoyance of the people of [Scunthorpe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe) etc.).

Comment: Thanks Richard, I read up on the Scunthorpe problem. However I am more concerned my code cannot pick up "  ass" becuase of the whitespace.

Comment: use String.test() instead of string.match() if you just want to know *if* the regex matches. And here is a link: [JavaScript RegEx Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Buy [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do). I have never found a more thorough, accurate or helpful explanation of regexes.

Comment: Also, you are going to need to escape those bad words unless you know for 100% sure that they contain only alphanumeric characters. For example, if you want to include 'd*ck' in the bad word list, then you'll need to escape the '*': `/d\*ck/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a corrected JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/d2rcx/5/

See the following documentation for RegExp:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Note that the second parameter is where you should specify your flags (e.g. 'g' or 'i'). For example:

```
new RegExp(badWords[i], 'gi');
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using Regex to do this you are probably better off just looping through an array of badwords and looking for instances within a string using [indexOf].(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Otherwise you could make a regex like...

```
\badword1|badword2|badword3\
```

and just check for any match.

A word boundary in Regex is `\b` so you could say

```
\\b(badword1|badword2|badword3)\b\
```

which will match only whole words - ie Scunthorpe will be ok :)

```
var rx = new RegExp("\\b(donkey|twerp|idiot)\\b","i"); // i = case insenstive option

alert(rx.test('you are a twerp')); //true

alert(rx.test('hello idiotstick')); //fasle -not whole word

alert(rx.test('nice "donkey"')); //true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F8svC/

Comment: But what about spaces etc , will this work in cases such as "   ass"

Comment: I don't understand the recommendation against a regex.  This is definitely a regex task!

Answer (score 2):

Please review http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp and note that fieldValue.match() will not return a boolean but an array of matches

Comment: That doesn't matter if you're using a type coercive conditional, which the OP is. The double equals (`==`) will return a truthy value if the array contains anything, but will return falsey value if it's empty. Not that I'd recommend this approach but this doesn't really answer the OP's question about RegExp; it's just picking on coding style which can come later, when the code is working.

Comment: "some".match(new RegExp(/some/)) => ["some"];    "some".match(new RegExp(/some/)) == true   => false;

Comment: Just tested this and you're right about the double equals. As I said I wouldn't recommended that approach, especially now you've pointed out it doesn't work, but this can be got round simply by changing the relevant line of code to `if (fieldValue.match(regex))`; if it's `null` then as far as the `if` statement is concerned, the result is false. JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/guypursey/yMCy4/1/). The point remains that your answer doesn't really address the OP's question but points off to a page about the `match` method which isn't so relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

Changing this, which requires a loop:

```
var regex = new RegExp("/" + badWords[i] + "/g");
```

for this:

```
var regex = new RegExp("/" + badWords.join("|") + "/g");
```

would be a start. This will do all the matches in one go because the array becomes one string with each element separated by pipes.

**P.S.**
Reference guide for RegEx [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). But there isn't a lot of clear information online about what is and isn't possible with respect to certain functions nor what's good code. I've found a couple of books most useful: David Flanagan's latest *JavaScript: The Definitive Guide* and Douglas Crockford's *JavaScript: The Good Parts* for the most usable subset of JavaScript, including RegEx. The railroad diagrams by Crockford are especially good but I'm not sure if they're available online anywhere.

**EDIT:** [Here's](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-good-parts-douglas-crockford-1st/chapter-7/an-example) an online copy of the relevant chapter including some of those railroad diagrams I mentioned, in case it helps.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the bad words.